# What to use to secure my spring boot Rest Api End points 'OAuth2 Resource Server' Or 'OAuth2 Client' in spring-security:6.2.1 with keycloak Oauth2

Tags: keycloak

I have Spring boot Rest API Application and i want secure my rest end point in <spring-security.version>6.2.1</spring-security.version> with Keycloak OAuth2 and here i am confused what to use
**OAuth2 Resource Server** or **OAuth2 Client**?

My Controller Class:
@Controller
@RequestMapping( value = "/server" )
public class FmServerController
{
private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger( FmServerController.class

);
private static final String MODULE = FmServerController.class.getSimpleName();

```
        @Autowired
        private FmUiLoggerUtility logger;

        @Autowired
        private FmServerService fmServerService;

        @Autowired
        private ConnectionService connectionService;

        @Autowired
        private CrossSiteScriptingValidator xssValidator;

        private ModelMapper modelMapper;

        static final int NO_UPDATED_FMSERVER_FIELDS = 0;
        static final int UPDATED_FMSERVER_NAME = 1;
        static final int UPDATED_FMSERVER_CREDENTIALS = 2;

        @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-name}")
        String userName;

        @RequestMapping( value = {"/add","/add/"}, method = RequestMethod.POST )
        public ResponseEntity<Integer> add( @Validated @ModelAttribute FmServerDTO fmServerDTO, BindingResult bindingResult,
            Principal principal ) throws CrossSiteScriptingException
        {
            xssValidator.handleValidationError( bindingResult );
            modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
            FmServer fmServer = modelMapper.map(fmServerDTO, FmServer.class);
            int id = 0;

            try {
                id = fmServerService.add( fmServer, userName );
                connectionService.addServerConnection( connectionService.createServerConnection( fmServer ) );

                logger.write( Level.DEBUG, MODULE, LOG, userName, "Successfully added " + fmServer.getName() );
                return new ResponseEntity<>( id, HttpStatus.OK );
            }
            catch( Exception ex )
            {
                logger.write( Level.DEBUG, MODULE, LOG, userName, "Failed to add " + fmServer.getName(), ex.getMessage() );
                return new ResponseEntity<>( id, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST );
            }
        }
    }
```

---

What code should i write in SecurityConfig?

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig
    {
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
              What to write here to secure my end poind with respect to keycloak and spring-securit:6.2.1?
    }
    }
```

Keyckloak Detail:

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=${AUTH_SERVER_URL}/${CONTEXT_PATH}/realms/AVA
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.token-uri=${AUTH_SERVER_URL}/${CONTEXT_PATH}/realms/AVA/protocol/openid-connect/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-name=${CLIENT_NAME}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=${CLIENT_NAME}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid,profile
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=client_credentials.

Please Help!!

I tried sevaral things but could not get result.

1-Tried this but not helped:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig
    {
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
              http.csrf(httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer.disable()).authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**")).authenticated()).oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
                    .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())

    }
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
            return JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation("https://domain-name/utf/auth/realms/AVA");
        }

    }
```

---

2-Tried this but not helped:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig
    {
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
              http.csrf(httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer.disable()).authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**")).authenticated()).oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults()).oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults());

    }
    }
```

Comment: I wrote a detailed guide for that [on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2)